# cant show details of a post of custom-post-type -wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, routes

I have custom post type like this

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_feedback' );

function create_post_type_feedback() {
    register_post_type( 'testimonial',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Feedbacks' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Feedback' )
            ),
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

In a page i am showing the list of the testimonials  and using the function get_permalink() to get hyperlink. To show details of a testimonial post i have "single-testimonial.php" and  but whenever  i click to view details of the testimonial it redirects me to a link like '..../testimonial/postname'. Though there  single-testimonial. php , it shows me the 404.php's content.

How can i show details of a post of custom-post-type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the single post pages to work you will have to add a few things to your register custom post type function... ie:

```
'public' => true,                            // yes you want it to be public?
'show_ui' => true,                           // you want it shown in the admin area
'show_in_menu' => true,                      // show it in menus etc..
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'testimonial'), // this is the permalink structure 
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,                 // show in navigation menus
'publicly_queryable' => true,                // include this in searches
'query_var' => true,                         // do you want to pass values?
'capability_type' => 'post',                 // is it like a post or page?
'menu_position' => 25,                       // the position on the admin menu!
```

adding the slug should do the trick, 
NOTICE: once slug has been set, go to settings->permalinks set back to default, then set back to postname, to flush the re-write rules, and so wordpress knows its there and working! that should do the trick, you dont need to add any template code to any files,

simply add the single-testimonial.php and it should work or
page-testimonial.php depending how you want it setup..

Marty

Answer (score 0):

In your single-testimonial.php, make sure you have this line at the top:

```
// Template Name: Single Testimonial template
```

This is so Wordpress can know that this is a template file and allow you to select it from the 'page attributes' section when you are creating a testimonial post.

Secondly, use the `get_post_permalink()` function instead of `get_permalink()`. Here's [why](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_permalink)